# Unscale the mean square error of standardized data

Tags: error-function, mean-square-error

I have a question please about the mean squre error resulting from the analysis of standardized data. How should I unscale it and use the real units of the variable.

I have standardized the data (Z) by removing the mean (average) and scaling to unit variance which make it unitless. Now, I want to return the resulting errors MSE and MAE to the actual unit. Regarding the MAE, should I multiply it the SD and add the data average of the output variable ?? and what about the MSE which should have a squared unit ? Should I multiply the standardized value to the squared SD and add the squared average (mean) ?

Since Z=(X−average)/SD
, So can it be returned as .. X=Z∗SD+average .. or this will be wrong ?

Comment: If this is about errors, it is unclear why you would want to "add the data average of the output variable".  Are you trying to develop a predicted value or a confidence interval?  If so, you will need to take a more sophisticated approach to the mean square error

Comment: Many thanks for your comment @Henry. I am simply trying to express the mean square error in real units of the output variable.